# Persistent storage maximum size reached

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

I am unable to test the code I have been developing due to this error in both Chrome and Firefox. I think it's because I've refreshed the page too many times. I have tried holding Ctrl as I refresh but no joy.

Comment: You're shoving too much in `localStorage`.

Comment: delete your storage in resources tab of dev tools. and/or increase the default storage limit `dom.storage.default_quota`

Comment: I was able to view the page after deleting local storage from dev tools, but how can I prevent this happening to my end user? Can the cache be overwrote when full?

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following options to delete the storage:

- delete your storage in resources tab of dev tools
- increase the default storage limit `dom.storage.default_quota`

Wrap all local/session storage setters in a try/catch block to delete programmatically.

```
try{localStorage.setItem("foo", "bar")} catch(e){localStorage.clear()}
```